# Передача прототипа через типовый параметр

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

#### Описание

Есть у меня некие классы `Elemental` и `Factory`. Что они делают - не важно, поэтому не задержимся на них. Проблема в том что у `Factory` есть функция `getCase`, которая в качестве аргумента должен принимать прототип какого-то класса, который наследуется от `Elemental`. Если я грубо беру и как тип параметра задаю `typeof Elemental`...

```js
class Factory {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {typeof Elemental} value 
     * @returns 
     */
    getCase(value) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

...то все хорошо, но если я пытаюсь задать гибкости с помощью типового параметра, который наследуется от `Elemental`...

```js
/** 
 * @template {Elemental} Type
 */
class Factory {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {typeof Type} value 
     * @returns 
     */
    getCase(value) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

...то выскакивает ошибка:

> "Type" относится только к типу, но используется здесь как значение.

#### Вопрос

Ошибка вроде логичная, но у меня вообще идей нет, а класс нуждается в типовом параметре. Какие идеи, решения могут быть для данной проблемы?

---

#### Дополнение

Я не знаю для чего, но если вдруг будут нужны исходники - [вот](https://github.com/eccs0103/Elements/blob/master/scripts/structure.js).

Answer (score 0):

> В **jsDoc** `typeof` предназначен для создания типа на основе возвращаемых данных или данных переменной.

```
/**
 * @type {{a: number, b: string}}
 */
const bigObj = {
  a: 4,
  b: '45'
}

/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @return {string}
 */
function func(name) {
  return `Привет ${name}`;
}

/**
 * @type {typeof bigObj}
 */
let c;

/**
 * @type {typeof func}
 */
let d;
```

> Однако взять тип данных из типа не получится. На что и указывает ошибка.

На примере ниже, есть 4 класса - Easy, Medium, VeryHigh, High. Medium наследуется от Easy. Hard и VertHard не наследуются ни от кого. На основе классов Medium и VeryHigh создадим **@typedef** тип данных с названием **SomeType** и укажем в методе `showHard` класса Hard тип данных SomeType для параметра `val`

```
class Easy {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 'dataProp';
  }
  /** @return {number} */
  showEasy() {
    return  1;
  }
}

class Medium extends Easy {
  showMedium() {
    return '2';
  }
}

class VeryHigh {
  showVery() {
    return [];
  }
}

/**
 * @typedef {Medium | VeryHigh} SomeType
 */

class Hard {
  /** @param {SomeType} val */
  showHard(val) {
    return {a: '1', b: 2}
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаете создать новый тип с помощью `@typedef` из всех наследуемых классов `Elemental`?

Comment: В любом случае, взять набор типов из типа не выйдет. Если у вас от `Elemental` наследуются 100500 классов со своими свойствами и все свойства всех этих классов вы хотите получить в одном типе(в параметре методе класса), то других вариантов, как перечисление, я не вижу.

Comment: Ситуация хуже, чем 100500 классов. :-)
Просто пользователь должен иметь возможность дополнить список таких классов не меняя исходники. Поэтому такое решение мне не поможет. Если решение не найдется, то уж лучше оставить как есть. Так основные функции поддерживаются.

Comment: Что за пользователь такой? Да и тип пользователь может уже самостоятельно расширять. + можно придумать систему сбора всех классов в один. Наследование никто не отменял. Однако, я не знаю точно, чего вы хотите добиться, смотрите сами ) Я не видел возможности ни в jsDoc, ни в TypeScript возможности вытянуть свойства дочернего класса\компонента. А что будет если и от дочернего унаследуются...